# Where to put a particular template helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a pageTitle template variable that is in the header element () of each section of my site, and I would like it to be dynamic, rather than hard-coded, so site maintenance is easier.

Using Meteor (I'm currently reading Discover Meteor), would it be best to put it in a Session variable, and then return the value from a Template helper (i.e. as in the example in the Session chapter of Discover Meteor), or is there an Atmosphere package that would handle this better?

Also, if I do put it in a Template helper, I'm a little fuzzy about where is the appropriate file in which to put the helper. That is, if I have a .js file for (almost) every template (because I'm following along with the book), would I really need to put the same helper code that returns the pageTitle variable from the Session in each template's .js file?

It seems inefficient to have so many redundancies, but if I had a single instance of that Template.templateName.helper() code, I'm not sure where to put it.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036248/meteor-setting-the-document-title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also fairly new to Meteor, but it looks like you could use the Observe Collection from the docs - http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe and have a collection with your pageTitles in it.

So it would be something like

`document.title = yourCursor.observe(function({
  changed: function(id, field){return field.pageTitle}
})`

As for location, anywhere on the client side should work.

Not sure if this is best way to do it, but hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a reasonable solution. I'm still too new to Meteor to be very opinionated about "The Way It Is Done" in this framework, but clearly it has quite different conventions than a typical server-side MVC framework.

Comment: I'm sorry to be intervening here, but this is not a good solution. Creating a collection involves a **lot** of overhead. This would be half way to a reasonable solution for a value that needed to be reactive. But the page title definetely doesn't need to be reactive. Reactivity is really nice, but it always comes at a cost. So try to avoid it where it isn't needed.

Comment: True, the page title won't change (for the most part) except when a user navigates around the site.  Should it be kept in a file or something? I solve this in different ways with different frameworks. It's usually only a problem with frameworks that use the "yield" pattern of template rendering, rather than piecing them together, because, with that pattern, usually everything but the content is kept in a single layout template that doesn't change between pages. Some frameworks require that you use different layout templates for different sections of your app, but that's rarely practical, imho.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put it inside a global helper. You can use [`Template.registerHelper`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper) for that. I usually put these helpers inside `client/helpers/global.js`. I'm not sure why you would want to use a session variable for this. But here's a simple example of how this helper could look like:

`client/helpers/global.js`

```
Template.registerHelper('setPageTitle', function (newTitle) {
  document.title = newTitle
})
```

Usage:

```
{{ setPageTitle 'Hi' }}
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want a session variable for this purpose. As I said in the question, I'm just working my way through the Discover Meteor book (http://discovermeteor.com), and this was the author's way of demonstrating Meteor's Session functionality, in the book's Session chapter.

Comment: Yeah, not a practical example -- I agree.