# Setting the document title with Meteor

Tags: meteor, title, spacebars

I'm just starting with Meteor. In an app which is to be localized, I want to set the document title.

I am following the [advice given by Bernát](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19010848/1927589)

In my barebones version, I have just 2 documents:

head.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{{localizedTitle}}</title>
</head>
```

ui.js

```
UI.registerHelper("localizedTitle", function() {
  var title = "Localized Title"
  document.title = title;
});
```

When the app loads, the document title is "{{localizedTitle}}". If I call `UI._globalHelpers.localizedTitle()` from the console, the correct title is shown.

What do I have to do to get the localized title to show when the page is loaded?

---

EDIT: This works for me, but it seems to be a bit of a hack. The `title` template does nothing but get itself rendered, which actually adds nothing to the interface.

body.html

```
<body>
{{> title}}
</body>

<template name="title">
</template>
```

title.js

```
Template.title.onRendered(function () {
  document.title = getLocalizedString()

  function getLocalizedString() {
    return "Title : in English"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Bernát's answer, your global helper should not be called in the head's `<title>` tag, but within the `<template>` tag of the template where you wish to have a given title. In Meteor, `<head>` does not count as a template, therefore you cannot use Spacebars notation in it: it will just be considered as simple text.

Also, keep in mind that your helper will not return (i.e. print) anything to the page. `document.title = "something"` directly assigns "something" to your ` tag. So no need to call your helper inside it!

So, say you want to have the "Localized Title" title for a page using the `localized` template :

```
<template name="localized">
  <h1>This is the localized page</h1>
  {{localizedTitle}}
</template>
```

Here, your trick should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it convenient to set the title in *onAfterAction* in my iron-router routes:

```
onAfterAction: function(){
  document.title = 'foo'; // ex: your site's name
  var routeName = Router.current().route.getName();
  if ( routeName ) document.title = document.title + ': ' + routeName;
}
```

Comment: I haven't started looking at iron:router yet. One thing at a time.

Comment: You'll eventually get there, or to flow-router ;)

Comment: In any event, @BraveKenny is right, the only way to set the document title is from javascript. The only issue for you is how to trigger that js to run. Your template's *onRendered* callback, iron-router, etc... are all effective choices.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more elegant solution is to make the title reactive and set it via a Session variable (other reactive data sources are of course also OK). Like that:

```
Template.body.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    document.title = Session.get('documentTitle');
  });
});
```

Now every time you set the 'documentTitle' variable with

```
Session.set('documentTitle', 'Awesome title');
```

the page title will change. No need for hacks and you can do this anywhere in your client code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
UI.registerHelper('title', function() {
 return 'LocalizedTitle'
});
```

we can use title where ever you want

you can use like this `{{title}}`